# How to instruct Qmake to prepend a folder name to all it headers and sources listed?

Tags: qt, qmake

I have a *Qt app pro file* lets say `MyQtApp.pro`. I have various platform specific files in different folders I want to compile on different platforms.

`OSXFiles` is the folder where lets say sources for OSX reside

```
macx {
    MY_FOLDER = OSXFiles

    SOURCES += $$MY_FOLDER/File_1.hpp $$MY_FOLDER/File_3.hpp $$MY_FOLDER/File_3.hpp
    SOURCES += $$MY_FOLDER/File_1.cpp $$MY_FOLDER/File_3.cpp $$MY_FOLDER/File_3.cpp
}
```

Above technique works but is there a way get rid of hassle of prepending `$$MY_FOLDER` to every file?
Isnt there some cool trick like this for instance which would understand that for every default look into `$$MY_FOLDER`?

```
SOURCES += $$MY_FOLDER/ += File_1.hpp File_3.hpp
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use a [for](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-test-function-reference.html#for-iterate-list) function

```
MY_FOLDER = OSXFiles
for(a, SOURCES){
    OSXFILES += $$MY_FOLDER/$$a
}
```

Or [join](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-function-reference.html#join-variablename-glue-before-after):

```
OSXFILES = $$join(SOURCES, " $$MY_FOLDER/", $$MY_FOLDER/)
```

Comment: Thanks that works. I was looking for a simpler trick but this works as well